# Values-list: a proper list must not end with 1 - nQueens

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I asked a question about my nQueens problem the other day and received many great answers so I thought I would ask again since I am very close to finishing this threat function. My function is to determine a threat on the horizontal, vertical, or diagonal. My input is like so:

(THREAT? '(1 3) '((1 0)(2 4)(3 7)(4 3)(5 2)(6 8)(7 5)(8 1)))

It gives a new given position and checks to see if putting it on the board would create any problems. The code I have up to now is as follows:

*I have split diagonal into its own function to make the code a little more readable

```
(defun diagonal(point1 point2)
    (= (abs (- (values-list ( car point1 )) (values-list (car point2))))
       (abs (- (values-list ( cdr point1 )) (values-list (cdr point2)))))
)

(defun THREAT?(x y)
    ; Checks threat on the vertical
    (when (not (eq (values-list (cdr (nth (- (car x) 1 ) y )) ) '0 ) )
            (return-from THREAT? t)
    )
    (loop for i from 0 to (list-length y)

            ; Checks threat on the horizontal
            when (eq (values-list ( cdr x  )) (values-list (cdr (nth i y))) )
                    do (return-from THREAT? t)
            ; With the help of the diagonal function checks along the diagonal
            when (diagonal x (nth i y) )
                    do (return-from THREAT? t)
    )
)
```

*The vertical and horizontal functions work fine as I have commented out diagonal and checked the two.

I receive the error message not at compilation but when running my code:

**VALUES-LIST: A proper list must not end with 1**

which I suspect is a problem in my diagonal function. I don't see why values-list would be a problem since I have used it a couple times in the very same code with no problems. I believe the diagonal function should be given two lists (1 3)(2 4) for example, take the car of each making it (1)(2) and then applying values-list and pulling the values out of the brackets to then be manipulated. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does `VALUES-LIST` do? Maybe you should check that first...

Comment: This is a good Lisp introduction: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/book.pdf

Comment: @RainerJoswig According to the main site, it seems like it should remove the parenthesis such as in this example that I found on that site: (values-list '(1)) =>  1. My values should only have 1 value inside of them due to the cars and cdrs, so if I am understanding that right it should result in the same way as that example did. I have used values-list before in the same program and they have worked in the way that this example reflected

Comment: Ever heard of the functions CAR and FIRST?

Comment: @RainerJoswig I am using CAR in this function, and it should work since I am importing sets of y one by one by using nth and grabbing their cars and cdrs. I could use FIRST, but I feel that this car and cdr solution also works since by looping, I am touching all of the y value sets and grabbing the corresponding values. For example (1 2) should be imported, split up using car and cdr (1)(2) and then like the values-list example should be removed from the parenthesis: 1 and 2 and then I should be able to manipulate them

Comment: The question is: what is the difference between (values-list '(1)) and (car '(1)) ???

Comment: @RainerJoswig Well car can't be used on single atoms so I don't believe it could work in this situation. When using multiple values, Values-list will remove all parentheses (1 2 3) => 1, 2, 3 while car will simply return the first value of a list (1 2 3) => (1) but in order to manipulate and compare which I will need to do I need to remove the parenthesis, and values-list has worked in that regard in other parts of my program

Comment: Funky, Common Lisp says: `(= (values-list '(1)) (car '(1))) --> T`  and `(= (values-list '(1 2 3)) (car '(1 2 3)))  -->  T`  How do you explain that?

Comment: Forget the idea of `removing parentheses`. There is nothing like `removing parentheses` in Lisp. Get rid of `values-list`, it makes no sense. The error comes from your program doing `(values-list 1)`.

Comment: Ah yes, I removed the values-list from the car functions and kept them on the cdr functions and this solved my issue right up. Only problem is that this diagonal function always seems to return true. For example inputting (THREAT? '(1 2) '((1 0)(2 4)(3 0)(4 0)(5 0)(6 0)(7 0)(8 0))) seems to return true when it shouldn't (1 2)(2 4) are not true. I commented it out and vertical and horizontal handle it fine so it must be an issue with diagonal. If when works like any other if statement but only having one outcome then it should only enter when diagonal is true but in this case it shouldn't ever.

Comment: "kept them on the cdr functions" -> this makes no sense either. I said you should remove VALUES-LIST. `(values-list (cdr '(1 2))` is the same as `(car (cdr '(1 2)))`, which is simply `(cadr '(1 2))`, which is better written as `(second '(1 2))`. Don't forget to check the intro book about Lisp, which I linked earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of using `values-list` makes no sense at all.

```
(defun diagonal (point1 point2)
    (= (abs (- (values-list ( car point1 )) (values-list (car point2))))
       (abs (- (values-list ( cdr point1 )) (values-list (cdr point2))))))
```

Now we call:

```
(diagonal '(1 3) '(1 0))
```

`point1` is `(1 3)`.

Now you call `(CAR '(1 3))`. The result is `1`.
Then you call `(VALUES-LIST 1)`. But why??? `(VALUES-LIST 1)` does not work, because `VALUES-LIST` expects a list as an argument. But `1` is not a list, but a number. --> **ERROR**

`VALUES-LIST` returns the contents of a list as multiple values. But since your code does not deal with multiple values in any way, it simply makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue. If you didn't see my comment, A problem is that this diagonal function always seems to return true. For example inputting (THREAT? '(1 2) '((1 0)(2 4)(3 0)(4 0)(5 0)(6 0)(7 0)(8 0))) seems to return true when it shouldn't (1 2) (2 4) are not true and the rest of the board is empty. I commented diagonal out and vertical and horizontal handle it fine so it must be an issue with diagonal. If WHEN works like any if statement but only having one outcome then it should only enter when diagonal is true but in this example it shouldn't ever enter.

Comment: @JohnBucher: you should now post that as a question with your current source code nicely formatted.

Comment: I made a new post about my logic error and removed values-list from the diagonal function of my code and replaced it with cars and cadrs